# TabViewBar not scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview, tabbar

I have a flutter app with page view having two tabs.

I added scroll view within the tab for the dynamic list to add into it. However it is not scrollable.

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Here's both the tab pages, both should be scrollable. But both tabs are not scrollable. I have tried to add and remove `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in some parts but none of them work.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:autoscale_tabbarview/autoscale_tabbarview.dart';

class RecipeDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String recipeName;
  final String estTimeMin;
  final List availableIngredients;
  final List missingIngredients;
  final Map<String, dynamic> instructions;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  const RecipeDetailPage({
    super.key,
    required this.recipeName,
    required this.estTimeMin,
    required this.availableIngredients,
    required this.missingIngredients,
    required this.instructions,
    required this.thumbnailUrl,
  });

  @override
  RecipeDetailPageState createState() => RecipeDetailPageState();
}

class RecipeDetailPageState extends State<RecipeDetailPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String totalIngredients =
        (widget.availableIngredients.length + widget.missingIngredients.length)
            .toString();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.recipeName),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child:
            // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
          children: [
            Image.network(widget.thumbnailUrl),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Icon(
                  Icons.timer,
                  size: 15,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 8,
                ),
                Text(
                  "${widget.estTimeMin} mins",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: TabBar(
                      controller: _controller,
                      tabs: const [
                        Tab(
                          child: Text(
                            'Ingredients',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          child: Text(
                            'Instructions',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  AutoScaleTabBarView(
                    controller: _controller,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                        children: [
                          ...widget.availableIngredients.map(
                            (ingredient) => ListTile(
                              leading: const Icon(
                                Icons.check_circle,
                                color: Colors.green,
                                size: 18,
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                ingredient,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                              visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                horizontal: 0,
                                vertical: -4,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          ...widget.missingIngredients.map(
                            (ingredient) => ListTile(
                              leading: const Icon(
                                Icons.question_mark,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                                size: 18,
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                ingredient,
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                              visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                horizontal: 0,
                                vertical: -4,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      ListView.separated(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          itemCount: widget.instructions.length,
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                              Divider(
                                color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                indent: 25,
                                endIndent: 25,
                                thickness: 2,
                              ),
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                                radius: 15,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      (index + 1).toString(),
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                widget.instructions['step${index + 1}'],
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                              visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                horizontal: 2,
                                vertical: 2,
                              ),
                              minLeadingWidth: 10,
                            );
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: a good way to fix this is reproducing the error in a simple example that we can run here and do the fix :)

Comment: I notice that in at least two places you've wrapped a ListView in a SingleChildScrollView. This makes no sense to me because ListView is inherently scrollable.

Comment: Initially i had only one SingleChildScrollView (top one) wrapping everything. But I added one after the tab view because that's not working. I just removed the SingleChildScrollView to only 1 but it's still not scrollable..

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve. What I did:

- Instead of having `SingleChildScrollView` wrapping from the top, I have `SingleChildScrollView` only wrapping the `ListView` widgets after the thumbnail image area.
- I set `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` for the other `ListView`s: (1) the tab names ('Ingredients' and 'Instructions'), (2) ListView of the ingredients and instructions.

My final code of the detail page is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:autoscale_tabbarview/autoscale_tabbarview.dart';

class RecipeDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String recipeName;
  final String estTimeMin;
  final List availableIngredients;
  final List missingIngredients;
  final Map<String, dynamic> instructions;
  final String thumbnailUrl;

  const RecipeDetailPage({
    super.key,
    required this.recipeName,
    required this.estTimeMin,
    required this.availableIngredients,
    required this.missingIngredients,
    required this.instructions,
    required this.thumbnailUrl,
  });

  @override
  RecipeDetailPageState createState() => RecipeDetailPageState();
}

class RecipeDetailPageState extends State<RecipeDetailPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String totalIngredients =
        (widget.availableIngredients.length + widget.missingIngredients.length)
            .toString();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.recipeName),
      ),
      body:
          // SingleChildScrollView(
          //   child: Column(
          //     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          //     children: [
          ListView(
        // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        // shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: (MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height) * 0.23,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6),
                  offset: const Offset(
                    0.0,
                    10.0,
                  ),
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                  spreadRadius: -6.0,
                ),
              ],
              image: DecorationImage(
                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                  Colors.white.withOpacity(0.35),
                  BlendMode.multiply,
                ),
                image: NetworkImage(widget.thumbnailUrl),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.7),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            const Icon(
                              Icons.schedule,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              size: 18,
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(width: 7),
                            Text("${widget.estTimeMin} mins"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                ListView(
                  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    // Align(
                    //   alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    //   child:
                    TabBar(
                      controller: _controller,
                      tabs: const [
                        Tab(
                          child: Text(
                            'Ingredients',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          child: Text(
                            'Instructions',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    // ),
                    AutoScaleTabBarView(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: _controller,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        ListView(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
                          children: [
                            ...widget.availableIngredients.map(
                              (ingredient) => ListTile(
                                leading: const Icon(
                                  Icons.check_circle,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  size: 18,
                                ),
                                title: Text(
                                  ingredient,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                  horizontal: 0,
                                  vertical: -4,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            ...widget.missingIngredients.map(
                              (ingredient) => ListTile(
                                leading: const Icon(
                                  Icons.question_mark,
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                  size: 18,
                                ),
                                title: Text(
                                  ingredient,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                  horizontal: 0,
                                  vertical: -4,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        ListView.separated(
                            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            // scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                            itemCount: widget.instructions.length,
                            separatorBuilder:
                                (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(
                                      color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.5),
                                      indent: 25,
                                      endIndent: 25,
                                      thickness: 2,
                                    ),
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                                  radius: 16,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        (index + 1).toString(),
                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                title: Text(
                                  widget.instructions['step${index + 1}'],
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                visualDensity: const VisualDensity(
                                  horizontal: 2,
                                  vertical: 2,
                                ),
                                minLeadingWidth: 10,
                              );
                            }),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      //     ],
      //   ),
      // ),
    );
  }
}
```